# Blender Depth of Field is not working

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to focus on an object and I used Depth of Field (Focus) on the object but blender is not focusing on that object. Blender rendering image normally. I'am using Blender Render.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want physically correct Depth of Field, you need to use Cycles render engine.

In Blender Internal you will get nothing, unless you add the effect in post-processing. Enable Compositing and use this node setup:

[image]

This reads your scene Z-values and your focal point set from your Camera object and adds the Depth of Field effect by blurring the image.

Also set your F-stop to some reasonable value, so you have something else than a pinhole camera. Only the value in the node has effect, the setting on the camera object is not used with Blender Internal.